# Convert time zone of datetime returned by f.datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

When I use f.datetime_select in a rails form, it returns a datetime to my controller in UTC, e.g.

```
2014-06-18T11:00:00+00:00
```

My local time zone is set to Melbourne (+10) as specified in my application.rb file:

```
config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'
```

So when I retrieve datatimes from my database they are automatically converted to Melbourne (+10) timezone, e.g.

```
2014-06-17 19:00:00 +1000
```

I want to compare the datetime returned by f.datetime_select with a field in my database. How can I do this?

i.e. how can i change the time zone of the datetime returned by f.datetime select to 'Melbourne' (+10) without changing the actual time? i.e. convert:

```
2014-06-18T11:00:00+00:00
```

to

```
2014-06-18T11:00:00+10:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dates stored in database are in UTC time. So when your app get new date from 'params' you basically have 2 options: to save it to the ActiveRecord model, and during that AR will perform all heavylifting of deciding of what timezone was meant.
If you don't want to save data to the model, you have to deal with it yourself. Date select control return just 3 specially formatted strings in params hash.
Let's say I named field in my form 'birthdate'. Controller will get something like:

```
"<your_model_name>" => {... , "birthdate(3i)" => "<day>", "birthdate(2i)" => "<month>", "birthdate(1i)" => "<year>", ...}
```

So you could deal with that info something like:

```
Time.zone.parse("#{ params[:model]['birthdate(3i)'] }-#{ params[:model]['birthdate(2i)'] }-#{ params[:model]['birthdate(1i)'] }")
```

And yeah I know that it looks ugly, and after some research I surprised that there is no any 'out of the box' solution )

Comment: Thanks this is a really clear and helpful response. I expected there might be some out of the box solution as well, but this works perfectly. Thanks again.